# about python virtualenv in windows 10 command prompt

Tags: python, virtualenv

installed python version is 3.8.1
i use command these
`py -m pip install --upgrade pip`
`py -m pip install --user virtualenv`
`py -m virtualenv kaggle_venv`

then, [i can see the created folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM2iY.png)

and

`.\kaggle_venv\Scripts\activate`

but do not work
how can solve this problem?

[i can't see '(kaggle_venv)' at the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmH9A.png)

Comment: Have you checked if it works, e.g. by running `python --version` or `pip list`? Maybe your prompt isn't showing due to some conflict.

Comment: you might be there already. ```pip -V``` , -V will contain path of virtual env. 
```(vams_test) C:\vams>pip -V
pip 19.2.3 from c:\vams\code\copy_v0.1\vams_test\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)```

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for your comment. i input `python --version` to my prompt but i can't see python version information. i think `pip list` is work.

Comment: So this is probably just a matter of the prompt. Have you checked `pip -V` as suggested by @drd?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen
@drd
thank you for your comment! very happy

i can see this message
`C:\Users\kaggle>pip -V
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\kaggle\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

i think `pip -V` do not contain path of virtual env!

Comment: Yes, looks like you are right. You can also check `PATH` to be sure - if you are in the virtual env, it should contain the path the virtualenv scripts at start.

Comment: Or check the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` which should be set if you are inside the virtual env.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I find something!
`C:\Users\kaggle>.\kaggle_venv\Scripts\activate

C:\Users\kaggle>pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\kaggle\kaggle_venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: `C:\Users\kaggle>.\kaggle_venv\Scripts\deactivate
C:\Users\kaggle>pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\kaggle\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: in short, "it is work"! but just prompt do not show let me know... i don't understand. it can make a mistake if i use multiple virtual environment.

Comment: I guess your prompt is set by some other software which overrides the virtualenv prompt. Maybe Xonsh, or something else you have installed...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen um... i don't know becuz i have just installed new windows 10 on desktop computer and only python 3.8.1. haha thank you

Comment: I just saw "XonshActivator" in the message, so I thought Xonsh was installed... anyway, it can also have to do with your language settings - I'm not really sure how this behaves for specific languages (just a guess).
Apart from that: it is always encouraged to directly add text (and images if needed) to the question instead of links (links can expire...).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for continuing to help me.oh, i will add text directly! :) first, i use venv instead of virtualenv, i can resolve problem that prompt do not show evironment name let me know! and i will check Xonsh, my language settings.